# Unable to make SIP calls using realtime with asterisk server

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip, pbx, asterisk-java

I am unable to make SIP calls to a Realtime SIP peer,but i am able to receive calls from them.I have made some test users using the sip.conf file,the calling operations work fine when i use them.But when i call a realtime sip peer the server disconnects by itself.

My sip peer is as follows:

> id  7006
>                             name  edwin
>                      canreinvite  yes
>                          context  internal
>                             host  dynamic
>                              nat  force_rport
>                             port  63806
>                          qualify  no
>                           secret  123
>                             type  friend
>                         disallow  all
>                            allow  g729
>                            allow  ilbc
>                            allow  gsm
>                            allow  ulaw
>                            allow  alaw
>                       regseconds  1577676814
>                           ipaddr  192.168.123.122
>                   cancallforward  yes
>                             avpf  yes
>                       allowguest  no
>                     allowoverlap  no
>                        srvlookup  yes
>                         localnet  192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0
>                         bindport  5060
>                         bindaddr  0.0.0.0
>                       soft_skill  32
>                   rtcachefriends  yes
>                 alwaysauthreject  yes
>                   session-timers  refuse

When i call this user from the user i made in my sip.conf file(shown below)  the server disconnects automatically:

```
[general]
context=internal
allowguest=no
allowoverlap=no
srvlookup=yes
bindport=5060
bindaddr=0.0.0.0
allow=ulaw
alwaysauthreject=yes
canreinvite=no
nat=force_rport
session-timers=refuse
localnet=192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0

[7001]
type=friend
host=dynamic
secret=123
qualify=yes
context=internal


[7002]
type=friend
host=dynamic
secret=456
qualify=yes
context=internal


[7003]
type=friend
host=dynamic
secret=789
qualify=yes
context=internal
```

I have enabled logging and the output is as follows:

> console dial edwin@internal
>   [Dec 30 03:40:46] WARNING[18968]: chan_oss.c:498 setformat: Unable to re-open DSP device /dev/dsp: No such file or directory
>   [Dec 30 03:40:46] NOTICE[18968]: console_video.c:136 console_video_start: voice only, console video support not present
>   pranav*CLI> 
>   Disconnected from Asterisk server
>   Asterisk cleanly ending (0).
>   Executing last minute cleanups

My Extensions table in my psql table is:

```
"2";"internal";"edwin";2;"Dial";"SIP/edwin,60"
"1";"internal";"edwin";1;"Answer";" "
"3";"internal";"edwin";3;"Playback";"vm-nobodyavail"
"4";"internal";"edwin";4;"Hangup";" "
```

So,how do i fix this so that i can receive calls using the user 'edwin'?

Comment: Can you confirm if db  is connected? and Asterisk can read peers? try to execute `sip show peer edwin`

Comment: @NasirIqbal yah it is connected.the above details of the peer are obtained by executing 'sip show'.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, probably you are running a VM or said machine does not have a sound card, So it is **not appropriate to use the console dial command**. Instead dial from a softphone or use originate command like

```
originate SIP/edwin application wait 11
```

If it does not solve your problem then there are multiple things which can make a user unreachable.

1. Ping both machines from each other to check if network is reachable
2. Make sure that **can register** option is enabled in client/softphone
3. Also test that asterisk can write to peer table. these entries should be changed on every new registration attempt (try from different hosts)

```
port 63806
ipaddr 192.168.123.122
regseconds 1577676814
```

4. Set **qualify=yes** to keep the registration/connection alive

Comment: hey thanks,i updated my asterisk and it seems to work fine now..also changed qualify to yes.